# ¿Como declarar una lista de objetos y luego asignarle datos? C#

Tags: c#, lista, objeto, constructor, class

Traté de buscar información al respecto y encontré que puedo declarar la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
var list= new List"object";
```

pero no me toma bien los diferentes tipos de sintaxis que encuentro de ejemplos en Internet.

¿ Como debería declarar la lista ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace TP
{

    public class AltaDeProducto
    {


        public AltaDeProducto()
        {
                //EN ESTE CONSTRUCTOR DEBERIA TENER EL LIST.            
        }
        public static ArrayList alta()
        {

            string respuesta = "si";

            while(respuesta=="si")
            {       
                //Declaro los objetos y comienzo con la carga de datos
                Productos producto; 
                producto = new Productos();

                Console.WriteLine("Usted eligio: Productos y Promociones"+"\n");
                Console.Write("Ingrese Tipo: ");
                producto.tipo = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ingrese Marca: ");
                producto.marca = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ingrese Talle: ");
                producto.talle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Ingrese Precio: ");
                producto.precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //Los agrego a la supuesta lista...

                AProducto.Add(producto);


                Console.Write("Cargado!"+"\n");
                Console.Write("Desea ingresar otro? ");
                respuesta=Console.ReadLine();       


            }

            // Devuelvo el producto para después utilizarlo.
            return AProducto;


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No es `var list= new List"object";`, sino en todo caso `var list= new List<object>();`. De todas maneras, es mejor usar el tipo en concreto que vas a usar, por ejemplo si es `string` : `var list= new List<string>();`

Comment: Y por cierto, no es necesario meterlo en un constructor. Añádelo a nivel de clase como te dije que debías hacer con `ArrayList` en tu anterior pregunta.

Comment: Ah ok, no importa si el objeto dentro tiene atributos de distinto tipo? porque a la lista le estaria pasando el objeto como string en el caso que me indicas creo no? o lo toma como objeto y ya?

Comment: ¿No te seria mas útil usar un List directamente? `List<objeto> lista =  new List<objeto>(); ` De esa manera podrias, como dice @Pikoh usarlo a nivel de clase y no tendrias problemas para añadirle objetos a la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ejemplo que pones de definición `var list= new List"object";` es incorrecto. La definición una lista genérica es [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), donde `T` es el tipo de datos que puede contener la lista.

Por supuesto, para el caso que nos expones, podrías perfectamente usar `var list = new List<object>()`, pero en ese caso perderías todas las ventajas que tiene utilizar una lista genérica con tipos definidos, como por ejemplo el uso de LINQ en ella.

En tu caso, en la lista que quieres definir los objetos que quieres introducir son de tipo `Productos`, por lo que la definición correcta es `var list = new List<Productos>();`. Añadir objetos de ese tipo posteriormente es simplemente usar el método `Add` en la lista. Si tratas de meter un objeto de otro tipo, lógicamente te lanzará una excepción. Te pongo el código completo como quedaría:

```
public class AltaDeProducto
{

    var AProducto = new List<Productos>();

    public List<Productos> alta()
    {
        string respuesta = "si";

        do
        {       
            //Declaro los objetos y comienzo con la carga de datos
            var producto = new Productos();

            Console.WriteLine("Usted eligio: Productos y Promociones"+"\n");
            Console.Write("Ingrese Tipo: ");
            producto.tipo = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Ingrese Marca: ");
            producto.marca = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Ingrese Talle: ");
            producto.talle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Ingrese Precio: ");
            producto.precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Los agrego a la supuesta lista...
            AProducto.Add(producto);

            Console.Write("Cargado!"+"\n");
            Console.Write("Desea ingresar otro? ");
            respuesta=Console.ReadLine(); 
        }while(respuesta=="si");

        // Devolvés la lista completa de todos los productos.
        return AProducto;
    }

    public void ImprimirLista()
    {
        foreach(var producto in AProducto)
        {
            Console.Write("Tipo: {0}. Marca: {1}. Talle: {2}. Precio: {3}.\n", producto.tipo, producto.marca, producto.talle, producto.precio);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Es justamente lo que estaba buscando, pasar los objetos de esa manera y desconocia que se podia declarar el metodo " public List<Productos> alta() " indicando el retorno del tipo "List<Productos>", espero haberme expresado bien, Muchas gracias! funciona de diez.

Comment: @Mariano Debes tener en cuenta que si tienes que acceder a este método desde otra clase, la clase `Productos` debe estar disponible también ahi. Por lo demás, `List<T>` es la mejor forma de manejar listas y cuando empieces a usar LINQ te darás cuenta de su potencia y versatilidad.

Comment: Claro estoy accediendo a esa clase desde otros archivos, quiero mostrarles como quedo el código y el error que me da al pasar la lista por parámetros, creo que tengo un error en la declaración de un método. Tengo que editar esta sección y agregar el código o genero una nueva pregunta?

Comment: @Mariano Creo que probablemente sea mejor una nueva pregunta. Por cierto, recuerda en tus preguntas aceptar aquella que te haya sido mas útil, es la forma de agradecer al que te ayuda y de que futuros usuarios que busquen lo mismo sepan que respuesta tiene posibilidades de ser la correcta.

Comment: Listo! en otra pregunta me informaron que debia instanciar la clase dentro del case para que tome lo que le estaba pasando. Ya di los agradecimientos. Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 2):

la definición correcta a tiu primera línea sería:

```
var list = new List<object>();
```

De ese modo se crea una lista genérica de tipo Object. Pero, lo recomendable es la creación de listas con tipos de datos concretos, como por ejemplo, una lista genérica de cadena de caracteres (strings):

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

Ahora bien, para trabajar con cadena de caracteres existe otra clase especializada que se denomina [StringCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), el cual básicamente es la mejora del tipo string[].

En el segundo bloque de código estás hablando de [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx), que es un vector de cualquier tipo de datos, que puede crecer o decrecer dinámicamente.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace TP
{

    public class AltaDeProducto
    {

        var AProducto = new ArrayList();

        public ArrayList alta()
        {
            string respuesta = "si";

            do
            {       
                //Declaro los objetos y comienzo con la carga de datos
                var producto = new Productos();

                Console.WriteLine("Usted eligio: Productos y Promociones"+"\n");
                Console.Write("Ingrese Tipo: ");
                producto.tipo = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ingrese Marca: ");
                producto.marca = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ingrese Talle: ");
                producto.talle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Ingrese Precio: ");
                producto.precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //Los agrego a la supuesta lista...
                AProducto.Add(producto);

                Console.Write("Cargado!"+"\n");
                Console.Write("Desea ingresar otro? ");
                respuesta=Console.ReadLine(); 
            }while(respuesta=="si");

            // Devolvés la lista completa de todos los productos.
            return AProducto;
        }

        public void ImprimirLista()
        {
            foreach(var producto in AProducto)
            {
                Console.Write("Tipo: {0}. Marca: {1}. Talle: {2}. Precio: {3}.\n", producto.tipo, producto.marca, producto.talle, producto.precio);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Espero resulte útil.

Comment: Por un lado, yo no aconsejaría nunca usar `StringCollection` sobre `List<string>` básicamente porque el primero implementa `IEnumerable` y el segundo `IEnumerable<T>`, con las ventajas que supone (LINQ por ejemplo). Por el otro,el OP no quiere una lista de `string`, sino de `Productos` por lo que yo entiendo. No se si simplemente te fijaste en mi comentario o no te diste cuenta :)

Comment: Tome los tips del uso del DO de este ejemplo, no queda en un bucle raro cuando vuelvo en el otro menu ahora, gracias man!

Comment: @Pikoh expliqué aquí los usos de Arrays. Entendí que su vector se refiere a productos. Simplemente dí una explicación extra para que se entienda la idea.

Comment: Ok, entiendo. De todas maneras lo principal que si que quería puntualizar el tema del uso de `StringCollection`, que yo no aconsejaría sobre `List<string>` :)

Comment: @Pikoh depende mucho del uso que quieras darle. Pero tampoco soy partidario de StringCollection por ser limitado.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es declarar una lista de un objeto creado por ti mismo, la sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
List<Producto> listaDeProductos = new List<Producto>();
```

Si lo que tienes es un objeto de productos por ejemplo y quieres añadirlo a una lista del mismo, puedes hacerlo utilizando la propiedad Add de las listas.

```
Producto producto = new Producto()
{
nombreDeProducto = txtNombreProducto.Text,
etc.
};
listaDeProductos.Add(producto);
```

Y con eso ya tienes un ejemplo del uso de las mismas!

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Perfecto, entonces puedo agregar los productos de esa manera sin preocuparme por los tipos. Gracias!